# No parameterless constructor defined for this object. c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Below this is my code, when i was debug why always get the error message :

`No parameterless constructor defined for this object.` in c#

```
 <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="Upload.LibraryDataContext" EntityTypeName="" TableName="BookInformations"></asp:LinqDataSource>
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="iSBN" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
     <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="iSBN" HeaderText="ISBN" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="iSBN" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="title" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="author" HeaderText="Author" SortExpression="author" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="publisher" HeaderText="Publisher" SortExpression="publisher" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="length" HeaderText="Length" SortExpression="length" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="categories" HeaderText="Categories" SortExpression="categories" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="publishYear" HeaderText="Publish Year" SortExpression="publishYear" />
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Book Cover">
             <EditItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("imgcover") %>'></asp:TextBox>
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imgcover") %>' />
             </ItemTemplate>
             <ControlStyle Height="200px" Width="200px" />
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="iSBN" Text="Update" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Update.aspx?iSBN={0}" />
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="iSBN" Text="Delete" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Delete.aspx?iSBN={0}" />
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Below is partial class :

```
public partial class adminpanel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
}
```

Comment: most likely it's the code behind that has an issue with it's constructor or a partial class is not well formed.

Comment: I guess `Upload.LibraryDataContext` doesn't have a parameterless constructor.  It's unclear from this code what the issue might be.

Comment: So how do i fix it?

Comment: For starters show us the code for that class so we can confirm that that is indeed the issue.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Upload
{
    public partial class adminpanel : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           

        }

       
    }
}

Comment: @JohnChong: Edit the post to show us your code, instead of using comment box.

Comment: please show the tiplines of the asp page. There might be a typo or a rename there.

Comment: Where to located

Comment: @JohnChong To be clear, I was asking for the code for `Upload.LibraryDataContext`, not your page.